# Angular2 C3 chart color is acting weird

Tags: angular, charts, c3.js

I'm testing different charting libraries on Angular 2, so I wrote serval directives on top of different charting libraries, such as D3, Flot, uvChart, etc
After I made a C3 chart, I got a weird graph from C3 [this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G3BR.png)

You can see the color between lines is reversed to black color, and when I hover it, the tooltip color becomes reversed to white color

Here are some part of my code

c3.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var c3: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[c3-chart]'
})

export class C3ChartDirective {
  $el: any;
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() options: string;

  constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    this.$el = jQuery(el.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.render();
  }

  // c3 chart render function
  render(): void {
    let elementID = '#' + this.$el.attr('id');
    console.log(elementID);

    let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: elementID,
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
  }
}
```

c3.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { C3ChartDirective } from './index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    C3ChartDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    C3ChartDirective
  ]
})

export class C3Module{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it's been a few days, no one answers my question. I solved it by myself. The problem is in the charting component, I have to including styleUrls link to correspond .css file for each charting directive.

Comment: Choose your own answer as the correct answer with the green question mark to receive some points :)